# Non-Static Method cannot be referenced from a static context JavaFX MVC

Tags: java, mvc, javafx

Estoy programando un ejercicio de clase y el programa (se trata de un programa que estoy desarrollando con Java FX) me da error y no comprendo por qué. En Java FX se usa el MVC, y tengo el siguiente código en "Conexion.java" en el controlador:

```
public Conexion getInstancia () throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{ 
    if(instancia==null){
        instancia=new Conexion(usuario, pass, host, puerto, baseDatos); 
    }
    return instancia; 
}
```

Este trozo de código lo que hace es aplicar el patrón Singleton, es decir, que no se pueda realizar más de una conexión a la BBDD a la vez. Hasta ahí todo bien, ya que en "Conexion.java" tengo todas estas variables declaradas y tal. Por si sirve, la variable instancia la tengo declarada de la siguiente forma:

```
private static Conexion instancia;
```

El problema lo tengo a la hora de, en el controlador de la primera vista, realizar la conexión. Básicamente pongo el siguiente código:

```
Conexion = Conexion.getInstancia();
```

Y me da el siguiente error: non-static method getInstancia() cannot be referred from a static context. No comprendo en qué me estoy equivocando, por más vueltas que le doy al código. Agradecería que se me explicara el error. Muchas gracias, saludos.

P.D. Esta pregunta se diferencia de otras parecidas, debido a que esto es Java FX y se trabaja con modelo MVC, lo que imagino que marca diferencias respecto a otras preguntas del mismo estilo.

Answer (score 1):

Sergio, antes de llamar al método que te devuelva la conexión (que de por cierto deberías refactorizar a un nombre mas descriptivo como `getConexion()`) debes acceder a la referencia UNICA que tu clase Singleton te brinda.

Como? Agregando un método `getSingletonInstanceClass()` que realizará lo siguiente:

```
public class MySingleton() {
  //CONSTANTE QUE INSTANCIA UNA NUEVA VERSIÓN DE LA CLASE
  private static final INSTANCE = new MySingleton();

  //METODO QUE DEVUELVE LA INSTANCIA UNICA DE LA CLASE SINGLETON
  public static MySingleton getMySingleton() {
     return INSTANCE;
  }

   //METODO PARA CONECTAR CON LA BASE
   public Connection getConexionSQL() throws SQLException {

    final String user = "sa";
    final String password = "1234";

    return DriverManager.getConnection("url", user, password);

  }
}
```

De esta manera vamos a poder acceder mediante `getMySingleton()` a la única instancia de nuestra clase (tanto el método como el atributo deben ser `static` para que no ocurra el error que planteaste) y con el método `getConexionSQL()` se nos será devuelta la conexion correspondiente.

Para utilizarlo en otra capa de nuestro proyecto sería algo como :

```
Connection conn = MySingleton.getMySingleton().getConexionSQL();
```

Espero te sirva! saludos.

Answer (score 1):

el Singleton lo tienes al 80%.
Te faltan dos cosas:

- Que tu método getInstancia sea static

  public static Conexion getInstancia ()
- Que tu método getInstancia sea synchronized, para que nunca se puedan dar condiciones de carrera en la creación de la instancia única.

  public static synchronized Conexion getInstancia ()

Con estos cambios tendrías listo tu Singleton.

Comment: Además, en este esquema de creación de Singletons, el constructor de la clase debe ser private

Comment: Y la respuesta a tu pregunta es que para poder acceder a Conexion.getInstancia() el método getInstancia tiene que ser estático. Es de eso de lo que se está quejando el compilador.
Con el código que tienes podrías hacer new Conexion().getInstancia() pero eso no sería un Singleton pues no garantiza que exista una única instancia de la clase Conexión